# Click on the dropdown value Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, popup

I have a dropdown and html input button. This dropdown has a value (for example "3"), this value calls popup. What i need is by clicking my button choose this value from dropdown and call the same popup.

Please help!!!! Thanks!

I try something like that

> onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('DropDown').value = 6"

But it's doesnt works

Comment: Provide code examples of what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
function popitup(url) {
    var newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="select-value">
    <option value="1">Test</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Open popup" onclick="popitup('/path/to/your/page.php?some_value=' + document.getElementById('select-value').value)" />
```

Comment: Sorry it's asp/net project, and all i need to choose this value to make event, that this value makes... popup is just for exanple..

Comment: You should specify which language you used